# Google Api Java client list root folder children

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client, google-drive-api

So, in Google Play Services, it's

```
final DriveFolder rootFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
```

To get root folder and then you can use parents feature.

In REST API, to list root children you had to add `'root' in parents` to a query parameter.

But there is no search query feature in Google Api Java client, or is it just that I haven't found it?

I can't use `Drive.Children.list(String)` because I have to find out the root folder id first.

Comment: the root folders id is root I believe so you shouldn't have to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DalmTo said in the comment above, the ID of the root folder is always "root". Additionally, the querying functionality you are looking for is in [`Drive.Files.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list), which has a `q` parameter for specifying a query.